# How to make fully covering index in mongo

Tags: mongodb

Let's say I have a document with such a structure:

```
_id: ObjectId,
user_id: int,
deleted: bool,
'additional.id': string, // optional field
synced_at: Date //optional field
```

example document will be:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dce551d6ad5bb1fd829bd77"),
    "user_id" : NumberInt(1),
    "additional" : {
        "id" : "hahahah"
    },
    "deleted" : false,
    "synced_at" : ISODate("2023-12-19T19:21:26.678+0000")
}
```

and I need to get a count of all the documents that match this query:

```
aggregate(
[
    {
        $match: {
             user_id: 1, 
             deleted: false,
  
             "additional.id" : {$exists : true},
             synced_at : {
                 $gte: new Date(new Date() - 7 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000)
             },
        }
    }
    ,
    {
        $count : "productsCount"
    }
]
)
```

So I created an index like this:

```
createIndex(
  {
      "user_id": 1,
      "deleted": 1,
      "additional.id": 1,
      "synced_at": -1,
  },
  {
      partialFilterExpression: {
        "deleted" : false,
        "additional.id" : {
            "$exists" : true
        },
        "synced_at" : {
            "$exists" : true
        }
    }
)
```

and let's say the query result is 20000. When I run a query with `.explain("executionStats")` I can see that `totalKeysExamined` and `totalDocsExamined` are both equal to 20000, and if I'm not mistaken it means that 20k products were taken from the index and additionally mongo made a lookup over all this 20k products. Checking deeper into execution stats I can see `Fetch` stage on top of the index:

```
"executionStages" : {
    "stage" : "FETCH",
    "filter" : {
        "$and" : [
           {
               "additiona.id" : {
                   "$exists" : true
                }
            ,
        ]
    },
```

So again if I'm not mistaken it means that Mongo taking all the needed documents (20k) from the index, but for some reason additionally checks each of 20k products if  `"additiona.id" : {"$exists" : true}` even if it's already in `partialFilterExpression`

Can I avoid this fetching stage somehow? I'm on Mongo 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB indexes are b-tree-like structures.  The value in the tree for a document is the list of the value of each indexed field.

There is no "value" that can be inserted when a document doesn't contain one of the field in the index, so `null` is used.

This means that the index entry for
`{user_id:1, deleted: false, additional:{id:null}}`
will be identical to the index for
`{user_id:1, deleted: false}`

When using the $exists operator, the first of these documents will match, while the second will not.

This means that the index can not determine which documents match without reading some of them in.

In the MongoDB query language, checking for `null` as a the value will match both explicitly set to null and non-existent.

This means if you change

```
        "additional.id" : {
            "$exists" : true
        },
```

to

```
        "additional.id" : {
            "$ne" : null
        },
```

The query executor can identify the matches without needing to examine the documents.

See https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-for-null-fields/#query-for-null-or-missing-fields

Depending on version, testing for `null` may also cause the query to not be covered.

If you can be certain that any existing value of "additional.id" will be a string, you can exploit the type-sensitivity of MongoDB query operators, and make that test:

```
        "additional.id" : {
            "$gte" : ""
        },
```

This will match any string, avoiding the [null bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-29326), and the existence check.

Comment: great, thank you, `"$ne" : null` did the trick, maybe you also know how I can add something like `"status : {$in : ["ok", null]}"`, mongo 5 partial filters do not support `$in` and `$or`, so if I'll have such status clause in my query it again will do a lookup

Comment: One hacky way to do that is to periodically run a multi-update like `db.collection.updateMany({},[{$set:{newBoolField:{$in:["$status",["ok",null]]}}}])`, then you can create a partial expression on `{newBoolField: true}`